# How to get more than 20 messages from Twitter Conversation Page?

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler

for research purpose I am trying to retrieve twitter pages. But the problem is that, if that page contains more than 20 messages it will only show the top 20 at the beginning. Only after you drag down the page, it will show you more. And my currently code only got the first 20 :(  Please help me, thanks!

```
f = urllib.urlopen("http://twitter.com/%s/status/%s" % (uid, sid))
```

one example will be https://twitter.com/DeanoLP/status/304476010257211394

Comment: Use Twitter's search API, don't try to make URL requests to the pages directly.

Comment: what you want is use this api https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: Hi All, thank you very much. I should state the problem more clear. I　want to get the 'view conversation' page.

Comment: @gstar2002 See: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/293

Comment: @Anorov Thanks for your pointer. I have read that page, it seems that, that api end point have been removed. So that I want to crawl that page....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your life would probably be easier if you queried twitter using the python twitter api wrapper: http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api()
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(uid, count=200)
```

The count parameter determines the number of statuses to retrieve (max=200).

NB: You can install this module quickly and easily via pip, but be sure to use:

```
pip install python-twitter
```

not

```
pip install twitter
```

which is a different wrapper.

Comment: Hi @David Marx, thank you for point to the library. I will try it later.